# Time stamp generation using Itext Pdf report, selenium

Tags: itext

I am writing a script for generating pdf report for test results. I need to add the time stamp for test starting time, test ending time.

Does iText support these features?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to add two text strings to a pdf report? The first string being the start of your Selenium test and the second string being the end of your Selenium test? If that is your question, then yes, iText can do that. But your question is confusing for me. It sounds the same like "can I write a start and end time to a log file in any format", of course you can.

Comment: Or do you happen to mean cryptographic time stamps?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear.

Comment: Yes, adding two text strings, one being the time the test started and the other the time the test run ended. Also if i can include the time taken to run each test case with the report, that would be helpful. Can you please elaborate about how to add the two time stamps?